# Constraints in Data Dictionary table creation

Tags: database, constraints, abap, sap-data-dictionary

How to set a constraint on a field value in an ABAP table so that it can contain any of 'n' possible values? For example, if I am entering a weekday, it can have either of only 7 possible values. Is there a consistency check setting for this during table creation?

Comment: Better use predefined domains, if possible. For such trivial tasks as weekdays there are standard domains in DDIC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use domains for this purpose. Table field => Data Element => Domain.
In the domain you can define possible values for that field. If your example with the weekdays is really what you need, than check out domain WEEKDAY in SE11.

Comment: Be aware that domain fixed values do not translate to database constraints - you could still add "day 9" to the table through faulty or malicious programming.